# Magento 2 install problem MultipleStoreViewPricing error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, error, extensions

I have a problem in Magento 2 installation. It shows  MultipleStoreViewPricing error
I run the below command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
I have attached screenshot of error [here](https://i.ibb.co/6W24Z7R/2019-09-26-161828.png)

Can any one help me

Comment: check if bss_giftcard_amount_stores table is present in database

Comment: No found table bss_giftcard_amount_stores